# OpenGL Text Engine

Tags: opengl

There are existing resources about how to render fonts in OpenGL (FTGL etc.)...I'm not asking about that. I want to know if there are any published libraries, algorithms, papers, etc. on dealing with text in 3d space intersecting geometry. For example, if you draw a label at a country location on a 3d earth, the geometry will often intersect the earth. I've seen some examples which always show the whole label, but then as the location of the label disappears around the back of the earth, the label shrinks and/or fades out.

Other things a text engine might handle is precedence for overlapping labels.

Comment: What is your question? How to draw text only for points on a map that are facing the camera? Can you clarify what you're looking for?

Comment: Are there any documented techniques/libraries for labeling items in a 3d scene without having the labels intersect geometry (as they often will if just drawing at the nominal label location and depth).

Comment: One easy way is to draw your geometry, turn off depth testing, then draw your labels.

Comment: sure, but then labels which would be completely hidden (e.g. label for country on far side of earth) would be visible

Comment: Sure, but if you use the normal of the polygon at the centroid of the country (or whatever), then you can cull those that are facing in roughly the same direction as the camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to work in 3D mapping. This is a hard problem. There is a wealth of literature on it. You will have to start googling and learning, there's not really any way around it.

Here are a few approaches:

- Draw the label at some height above the ground, try to pick a good height
- Try to contour the label over the ground (requires computation)
- Rasterize the labels onto textures so they are just part of the imagery
- Use stencil buffer tricks to slice the text (or roads etc.) into the geometry (can suffer from stretching artifacts)

Answer (score 2):

While I can't recommend a suitable library, I do know an extremely efficient way to render 2D text labels in a 3D world.

Let's first discuss the most efficient way to render any 2D text in OpenGL and then apply this knowledge for text labels that should move whenever the camera moves. A great way to render text is as follows:

- Create a texture containing all the characters of the font you'd like to use. Either render each character at the required size, or use signed distance fields if you want to scale the text to any size without much loss in quality. Store additional information, like the texture coordinates for each character as well as kerning information, in a separate file. A great tool to create signed distance field font textures can be found [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/491938-signed-distance-bitmap-font-tool/).
- Using the text string as input, create a 2D mesh containing a single quad (or 2 triangles) for every character in the text. Set the correct texture coordinates for each vertex. Kerning and word wrapping can be done correctly using the font information. For best performance, store the mesh in a vertex buffer object.
- To render the text, simply bind the texture and render the mesh.

Exact implementation details are beyond the scope of this post, but you can find a link to sample code at the end of this post.

To render 2D text labels in a 3D world, we will have to update the position of each label every time the camera moves. This would require to recreate the mesh every frame, which can be quite CPU intensive and may drop your frame rate to unacceptable levels.

A nice solution is to encode the 3D world position of your label in your mesh and use a vertex shader to move each label to the corresponding 2D position every frame. All you need to do is add a vertex attribute to each vertex in the mesh (or abuse a 3D texture coordinate for this) and store the 3D world position. The actual vertex should not be specified in world or screen coordinates, but should be relative to (0, 0).

When drawing the mesh, your vertex shader then reads the 3D position from the attribute or texture coordinate, converts it to screen space and offsets the vertex. Even though this seems inefficient, the fact that all data needs to be sent to the GPU only once and all processing is done in parallel on the GPU without involvement of your CPU, allows you to render thousands of 2D labels at very high frame rates.

An implementation of a system like this, compatible with Visual C++ 2010, can be found [here](https://github.com/paulhoux/Cinder-Samples). See the TextRendering sample for the text label classes, and see the Stars sample for information on how to use it. This code is intended for use with the Cinder C++ library: http://libcinder.org

A video of the Stars sample can be found [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRIEjOPp7is).